# Is there anyone that says that the "us" in "let us make man btzelem elokim" is referring to humans?

Tags: creation, parashat-bereishit

Is there anyone that says that the "us" in "let us make man btzelem elokim" is referring to humans I'm working on a d'var Torah at the moment and hoping for a source to back the idea up that Hashem was telling us to continue working on it.

Comment: let us make men in our image. If us there refer to humans, then who are the we in "our" image? Humans already are in humans image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it - apparently the Yismach Moshe says this.  At least according to http://www.youngisrael.org/content/parsha/01%20Beraishis/Berayshees08MichaelBorenstein.cfm and other divrei torah have come across online

Comment: Does anyone have any biographical information about him?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moshe_Teitelbaum_(Ujhel)

Comment: @MosesSupposes link dead

Answer (score 2):

There's a well-known comment (I don't recall who off-hand) that it's G-d's invitation to the person reading the text.

On a related note, Rabbi Ovadiah Sforno (Italy, died c. 1550) has the fascinating concept that each person decides for him/herself just how G-dly they will be; thus, how much do they fulfill the original engineering specification of "in G-d's likeness." (This appears in Sforno's essay prefacing his commentary on the Torah.)